# Error PLS-00201 : el identificador se debe declarar

Tags: sql, oracle

estoy iniciándome en PL/SQL y estoy realizando un ejercicio, que consiste en insertar tablas con distintos bucles. El enunciado del problema es este:

Escribir un procedimiento sin parÃ¡metros creaHabitaciones para rellenar la tabla habitaciones con los datos del hotel. E
l hotel dispone de 12 plantas de habitaciones, numeradas de la 1 a la 12.  En cada planta de la 1 a la 11 hay 25 habitaciones:
20 dobles (numeradas de 1 a 20) y 5 sencillas (de la 21 a la 25).  En la planta 12 sÃ³lo tiene 8 suites numeradas de la 1 a la 8.

Bueno, a continuación os dejo el código que he realizado y pienso que está bien realizado pero no sé por qué me sale error.

```
Procedure creaHabitaciones is
begin 
    doble:=1;
    sencilla:=21;
    for i in 1..12 loop --num plantas
       
        if i=12 then
            for j in 1..8 loop
                insert into habitaciones values(12,j,'Suite');
            end loop;
        else 
            while doble<=20 loop
                insert into habitaciones values(i,doble,'Doble');
            end loop;
            while sencilla <=25 loop
                insert into habitaciones values(i,sencilla,'Individual');
            end loop;
        end if;
        doble:=1;
        sencilla:=21;
    end loop;
end;
```

Os dejo los errores que me ha mostrado SqlDeveloper:

```
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 5:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'DOBLE' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 3, columna 5:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'SENCILLA' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 3, columna 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 11, columna 19:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'DOBLE' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 11, columna 13:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 14, columna 19:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'SENCILLA' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 14, columna 13:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 18, columna 9:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'DOBLE' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 18, columna 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 19, columna 9:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'SENCILLA' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 19, columna 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Si alguno sabe el error que me lo comente, llevo tiempo intentándolo y nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tu procedimiento le está haciendo falta una sección `declare`, que es donde defines las variables que vas a utilizar, por ejemplo:

```
create or replace procedure creaHabitaciones is
declare
  doble integer;
  sencilla integer;
begin 
  doble := 1;
   ...etcétera
end;
```

Esta sección siempre debe ir antes del `begin` (PL/SQL te recordará un poco a pascal, no solo por esto).

En una declaración de un procedimiento, de hecho, la palabra `declare` se puede obviar, por ejemplo:

```
create or replace procedure creaHabitaciones as
  doble integer;
  sencilla integer;
begin 
  doble := 1;
   ...etcétera
end;
```

Cualquier variable *local* que quieras utilizar en tu rutina debe estar declarada dentro de esta sección.

[Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#BABEABGF)

Comment: Cierto, me faltó el declare +1

Answer (score 0):

Debes declarar correctamente las variables, la sintaxis es:

> nombre de variable (tipo de dato) := valor

En tu caso debe quedar:

```
 doble integer := 1;
 sencilla integer := 21;
```

Fuente: [Variables en PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/constantvar_declaration.htm)